# Assign snmpbulkwalk output to associative array in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array, net-snmp

I've searched high and low for an answer but the solution continues to evade me. Below are the results of an `snmpbulkwalk` that I'm running against a local server.

```
snmpbulkwalk -v2c -Oqs -m EGT-VIPr-TRx -c <community> <ip> egtViprOutputMuxSecDestPort | sed -e 's/egtViprOutputMuxSecDestPort\.//g'
Output
1 2001
4 2002
5 2003
8 2004
```

My goal is to assign this output to an associative array in bash (ex `array[1]=2001, array[4]=2002, ...`). Below is the code that I've used in the past when assigning `snmpbulkwalk` output to a standard array. However I've had no success with associative arrays.

```
declare -A array
array=($(snmpbulkwalk -v2c -Oqs -m EGT-VIPr-TRx -c <community> <ip> egtViprOutputMuxSecDestPort | sed -e 's/egtViprOutputMuxSecDestPort\.//g'))
echo ${array[1]}

Output
array: 1: must use subscript when assigning associative array
array: 2001: must use subscript when assigning associative array
array: 2: must use subscript when assigning associative array
array: 2002: must use subscript when assigning associative array
array: 3: must use subscript when assigning associative array
array: 2003: must use subscript when assigning associative array
array: 4: must use subscript when assigning associative array
array: 2004: must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workable solution and I'm posting the answer for future reference.  After much trial and error a `while read` loop accomplished my ultimate goal.

```
declare -A array

while read id value; do
        array[$id]=$value
done < <(snmpbulkwalk -v2c -Oqs -m EGT-VIPr-TRx -c <community> <ip> egtViprOutputMuxSecDestPort | sed -e 's/egtViprOutputMuxSecDestPort\.//g')

echo ${array[1]}

Output
2001
```

I struggled somewhat with the syntax for reading the output from `snmpbulkwalk` into my loop, but the code above works perfectly in my scenario.